# How to find the image of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a step-by-step solution on how to find the image of a matrix. For example, if the matrix is as following:
$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
2 & -3 & 5 & -9\\
1& -2& 4 &-8\\
1 &-1 &1 &-1\\
1& -2& 4& -8
\end{matrix}\right]$$

I know the answer is $\operatorname{im}A=\operatorname{Span}\{(1,1,0,1)^t, (1,0 ,1,0)^t\}$.

I have no idea how to get to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Definitions**

The image of a matrix $A$ is the set of all vectors $Av$ where $v$ is a vector $A$ can act upon.

The span of a set $v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$ is the set of all linear combinations of these vectors. 
For example, span (0,2) is the line (0,x) for all x real. And span{(0,1), (2,1)} is the whole plane.

**Reasoning**
Since any four dimensional vector v can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors $(1,0,0,0)^T,(0,1,0,0)^T,(0,0,1,0)^T,(0,0,0,1)^T$, and that the image of one of these vectors is a column of the matrix $A$ (why?) you can check that the image of $A$ is the span of its columns read as vectors.

Answer (score 0):

$im(A) = im(T_A) $

where $T_A$ is a linear transformation , define by $$T_A(v) = Av $$

$$T_A:F_{col} \to F_{row} $$

where $$A_{row X col} $$

to find A's image you can simply do span of A's columns, and if you want a basis for it, remove dependent vectors.

Comment: Can you elaborate on my example? I have no idea what span and basis is.

Comment: @KyanaShayan Yes, your image of A is simply span(column1 , ... , column4)

Comment: If you are asked to find a basis for the image, you need to find out which vectors are dependent and drop them.